# How to prefer global npm rather than local one, inside npm scripts?

Tags: npm

I have an almost weird scenario:
My project depends on `cordova-lib@6.5.0` package, which has `npm@^2.10.x` as it's dependencies!
The worst thing about it (I think) is that it takes away my global `npm` while running `npm` scripts.
beside its a bad thing, should avoid using it, maybe an update fixes this, etc ... I am looking for a way/hack/workaround for situations like this.
Suppose I have a script in my `package.json`:

`"scripts":{
    "libs:update":"npm update bizotop-common-ui-components"
}`

when I run `npm run libs:update`, the local npm (2.10.x) runs instead of my global one (6.1.0).

If I have to keep having npm@2.10.x as my local dependency, do you know any hack/workaround so that I can run my global version of npm in my npm scripts in this kind of situation?

Thanks! +1

Comment: You could run `which npm` in your terminal to get path to npm. Then  use the path it returns in your npm-script. E.g. `"libs:update": "/usr/local/bin/npm update bizotop-common-ui-components"` _(Note; the `npm` part in your scipt has changed to `/usr/local/bin/npm`)_. Don't do this in production code as the global path may vary on each machine. If you're using Windows _cmd.exe_ you need to run `WHERE npm`, instead of `which`, to get the path. Then use the path `WHERE` returns in npm-script. For example: `"libs:update": "\"C:/Users/UserName/foo/bar/npm.cmd\" update bizotop-common-ui-components"`

Comment: thanks @RobC ! I'm looking for dynamic way of doing this (exactly what u mentioned: the one that works on every system). Your comment lit the way for me I think, I will try to do what I want. If successful, I'll share it as a `npm` package : ). Thanks man